# How to unlock fields in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am fairly new to Dynamics CRM, and I'm a little stuck. I want to edit the member type field within the Marketing List entity however the field is locked.
Is there any way to unlock this?

PS: I know someone has already asked this question for 4.0 but from what I understand the code is slightly different in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to edit the member type field of the Marketing List to add new entities, you need to choose between the standard values: `Account`,`Contact`,`Lead`